# Best way to register plugin capabilities with parent app

Tags: .net, plugins, architecture

The scenario is as follows...

Main app supports a number of parallel tasks each of which can be long-running and may need to grab user input at any time (grab focus).

The known/supported tasks will be provided by plugins.

I currently envisage something like:

App exposes: `SearchWeb` and `MonitorServer` which implement `ITask` (effectively as abstracts)
User chooses `MonitorServer` which results in a new instance of `MonitorServer` wel'll call `MS1`. They kick off another we'll call `MS2`

Now... for UI reasons, only one active task can be "focused" - similar to multiple open windows, only one can be on top.

So... What I need is a way for the plugins to expose which tasks they support and also, when the user picks a given task, to instantiate a concrete and monitor the status of it. In addition, I need the plugin to be able to open windows which the main app is aware of... Eg I can issue a "Close all  windows" from the main UI.

I know how to use reflection to scan for all assemblies which implement a given interface (`ITask`) and I can load it all in a seperate app domain so that I can reload the plugins if anything dies (Does anyone know of any reason not to have an app domain per concrete task? It would allow any individual task to die without impact on the rest)

It's worth nothing that while plugins are currently all provided by us, we're expecting 3rd party in future, so I need to make sure it handles rude/badly written plugins.

Background: I've got Unity building object trees so instantiation isn't a problem - it's more a question of how to register the capabilities.

Should `ITask` be:

`Sub RegisterTasks(Container as IContainerWrapper)`

(which would be called each time the container is reinitialised)
or perhaps:

`Property SupportedTasks As IEnmerable(Of System.Type)`

or something else entirely?

I can get the metadata (Task name, description, unique key) from attributes on the ITask

Thanks for your input.